# Why CSS,JS and images are not loading in webpage? I've following every possible solution. It's first time I'm experiencing this in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, css, continuous-integration

Why CSS,JS and images are not loading in webpage? I've following every possible solution. It's first time I'm experiencing this problem in codeigniter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Yod.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice: Try to don't use ../../../.. to load a file as you do for "online lib", if you use a cdn, just load like that:

```
<script src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

For your issue, we don't know where are the files you load, but often when you want go to root with xamp or wamp with base_url, you are in "localhost", so if your project is in a sub directory, it will return a 404 cause the file doesn't exist.

I'm sure if you go on "network" tab on your browser (mine is chrome), you will see only 404. Example: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXoVa.png

You can right click on a link, and open it on a new tab to see what is the file/image URL in your browser. Here is the issue :-)

Comment: Thanks :)
Problem has been solved.
I look into network and find which css file is not loaded on website..